# SQLiteException: no such column: _id (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)

Tags: android, sql

Вот таблица

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_MEMBERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + MemberEntry.TABLE_NAME + "("
                + MemberEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + MemberEntry.COLUMN_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + MemberEntry.COLUMN_LAST_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + MemberEntry.COLUMN_GENDER + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                + MemberEntry.COLUMN_SPORT + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_MEMBERS_TABLE);
    }
```

При компиляции приложения выходит ошибка

```
2023-09-05 16:58:06.064  5508-5508  AndroidRuntime          com.exampleandroid.olympusclubcopy   D  Shutting down VM
2023-09-05 16:58:06.070  5508-5508  AndroidRuntime          com.exampleandroid.olympusclubcopy   E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    Process: com.exampleandroid.olympusclubcopy, PID: 5508
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT _id, firstName, lastName, gender, sport FROM members
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:986)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:593)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1443)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1290)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1329)
        at com.exampleandroid.olympusclubcopy.data.OlympusContentProvider.query(OlympusContentProvider.java:45)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1239)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1332)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:267)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:944)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:880)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:836)
        at com.exampleandroid.olympusclubcopy.MainActivity.displayData(MainActivity.java:51)
        at com.exampleandroid.olympusclubcopy.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:39)
```

Система указывает ошибку в методе query ContentProvider

```
  private static final int MEMBERSOLO = 111;
    private static final int MEMBERS_ID = 222;
    private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

    static {
        uriMatcher.addURI(OlympusClubContract.AUTHORITY, OlympusClubContract.PATH_MEMBERS, MEMBERSOLO);
        uriMatcher.addURI(OlympusClubContract.AUTHORITY, OlympusClubContract.PATH_MEMBERS + "/#", MEMBERS_ID);

    }

public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor;
        int match = uriMatcher.match(uri);
        switch (match) {
            case MEMBERSOLO:
                cursor = db.query(MemberEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                        null, null, sortOrder);
                break;
            case MEMBERS_ID:
                selection = MemberEntry._ID + "=?";
                selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};
                cursor = db.query(MemberEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                        null, null, sortOrder);

                break;

            default:

                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cant query incorrect URI " + uri);
        }

        return cursor;

    }
```

Так же ошибка в методе display + onStart

```
protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        displayData();
    }

    private void displayData() {
        String[] projection = {
                MemberEntry._ID,
                MemberEntry.COLUMN_FIRST_NAME,
                MemberEntry.COLUMN_LAST_NAME,
                MemberEntry.COLUMN_GENDER,
                MemberEntry.COLUMN_SPORT,
        };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MemberEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
        dataTextView.setText("All members\n\n");
        dataTextView.append(MemberEntry._ID + " " +
                MemberEntry.COLUMN_FIRST_NAME + " " +
                MemberEntry.COLUMN_LAST_NAME + " " +
                MemberEntry.COLUMN_GENDER + " " +
                MemberEntry.COLUMN_SPORT);

        int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MemberEntry._ID);
        int idFirstName = cursor.getColumnIndex(MemberEntry.COLUMN_FIRST_NAME);
        int idLastName = cursor.getColumnIndex(MemberEntry.COLUMN_LAST_NAME);
        int idGender = cursor.getColumnIndex(MemberEntry.COLUMN_GENDER);
        int idSport = cursor.getColumnIndex(MemberEntry.COLUMN_SPORT);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int currentId = cursor.getInt(idIndex);
            String currentFirstName = cursor.getString(idFirstName);
            String currentLastName = cursor.getString(idLastName);
            int currentGender = cursor.getInt(idGender);
            String currentSport = cursor.getString(idSport);

            dataTextView.append("\n" +
                    currentId + " " +
                    currentFirstName + " " +
                    currentLastName + " " +
                    currentGender + " " +
                    currentSport);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Сontract

```
public final class OlympusClubContract {

    private OlympusClubContract () {

    }

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "olympus";
    public static final String SCHEME = "content://";
    public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.exampleandroid.olympusclubcopy";
    public static final String PATH_MEMBERS = "members";

    public static final Uri BASE_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(SCHEME + AUTHORITY);
    public static final class MemberEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "members";

        public static final String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
        public static final String COLUMN_FIRST_NAME = "firstName";
        public static final String COLUMN_LAST_NAME = "lastName";
        public static final String COLUMN_GENDER = "gender";
        public static final String COLUMN_SPORT = "sport";

        public static final int GENDER_UNKNOWN = 0;
        public static final int GENDER_MALE = 1;
        public static final int GENDER_FEMALE = 2;

        public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.withAppendedPath(BASE_CONTENT_URI, PATH_MEMBERS);

    }
}
```

Comment: Рискну предположить, что таблица `members` создавалась ранее без столбца `_id`. Попробуйте дропнуть ее и создать заново.

Comment: Если вы имели ввиду, удалить код из метода OnCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) скомпилировать приложение, а затем вставить код обратно, то это не помогло

Comment: Нет, не это. Я о `DROP TABLE members` а потом создать ее заранее кодом из `OnCreate`. Либо удалите db файл, если у вас там всего одна таблица.

Comment: Можно проверить содержимое базы через инспектор https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database или скопировать на ПК и открыть в любом БД-менеджере. Если колонки там нет - значит вы редактировали код создания таблицы после того как она уже была создана. Метод хелпера `onCreate()` вызывается единожды, при создании файла базы - дальше для изменений БД вы должны повысить версию базы и выполнить изменения в методе хелпера `onUpgrade` (это касается уже опубликованных приложений, в разработке лучше удалить файл БД или приложение и запустить заново, чтобы не усложнять код лишними апгрейдами).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена, причиной было, как сказали в комментариях, то, что колонка `_id` была редактирована после того, как была создана.

Я понизил версию таблицы до 1, и переустановил приложение. Все получилось